# Android Check if the storage space is low on app boot

Tags: android, local-storage

I think I can use Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW within a broadcast receiver to notify me when the device storage is low.
Explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117881/when-is-the-intent-action-device-storage-low-broadcasted/8118832#8118832).

I know that I could find out how much space the user has available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133417/android-get-free-size-of-internal-external-memory).

However, I want to avoid having to set a boundary of what is/isn't enough space available if possible. The OS gives the user a notification when the storage is low.

**Question**: Is there anyway of only showing an in app error message on boot if the OS thinks the space available is low?

Comment: Listen for the `ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW` broadcast? "This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system." but it will and should be fired by the device.

Comment: The solution that I was hoping for would be to do a check on start up, rather than at any point in the apps lifetime. The problem with a broadcast is it could come back at anytime. Reason I don't want this is because if the user is in the middle of doing something I don't want this interfering and ruining their user experience.

Comment: If I can't do a check the fall back is just making my own check on startup... but I'm not sure how much space available counts as "too low" so I was hoping I could get the OS to decide for me.

Comment: Then you just need to catch `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast and run your check code. Default value for "low storage" is 10%.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per some [related sample code from google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/photo-demo/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/photo/PhotoViewerActivity.java#L91) you can take this route:

```
IntentFilter lowstorageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW);
boolean hasLowStorage = registerReceiver(null, lowstorageFilter) != null;
```

In other words, there is a `DeviceStorageMonitorService` service that runs at the OS level and detects a low storage situation. From there, it sends a sticky broadcast that any activity or service can check, later. In this example, they registered a null receiver as a way to just test if the sticky broadcast has been sent.

Comment: This is deprecated in API level 26 now.

Comment: I will try `if (storageDir.getUsableSpace() * 100 / storageDir.getTotalSpace() <= 10)` to check if I have room to write

Comment: Here's my answer in which it works even if it's deprecated https://stackoverflow.com/a/69727078/5135372