# Android vision - Face detector dependencies are not yet available

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-vision

I am trying to test the google mobile vision api, for face detection, so I started with the demos from [GitHub mobile vision](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/tree/master/visionSamples). I tried both apps, FaceTracker and photo-demo, and the same issue rises with downloading the native face detector library.

For Nexus 5x, Galaxy S6 Edge not working, Galaxy S4, Galaxy Alpha is working.

What I see in the logs, when not working is:

For the app:

```
05-19 17:52:07.301 14909-14909/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo-1/lib/arm64
05-19 17:52:07.725 14909-14909/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo-1/lib/arm64
05-19 17:52:08.043 14909-14909/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo D/ChimeraCfgMgr: Reading stored module config
05-19 17:52:08.068 14909-14909/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/00000001/n/arm64-v8a
05-19 17:52:08.077 14909-14909/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo D/ChimeraFileApk: Primary ABI of requesting process is arm64-v8a
05-19 17:52:08.079 14909-14909/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo D/ChimeraFileApk: Classloading successful. Optimized code found.
05-19 17:52:08.105 14909-14909/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo I/FaceDetectorCreatorImpl: Requesting download for vision face detector
05-19 17:52:08.107 14909-14909/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo W/FaceDetectorHandle: Native face detector not yet available.  Reverting to no-op detection.
05-19 17:52:08.253 14909-14909/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo W/PhotoViewerActivity: Face detector dependencies are not yet available.
05-19 17:52:08.263 14909-14941/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-19 17:52:08.312 14909-14941/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 63c06b2, I8366cd0437
                                                                                          Build Date                       : 12/06/15
                                                                                          OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.05.13.02
                                                                                          Local Branch                     : mybranch17112971
                                                                                          Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BF64.1.2.9_v2
                                                                                          Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                                          Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
05-19 17:52:08.317 14909-14941/com.google.android.gms.samples.vision.face.photo I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
```

After doing some digging in the logs, by applying the vision filter for tags I see:

```
05-19 17:52:08.124 10421-10526/? I/Vision: Attempting to open download_details.json in com.google.android.gms.vision
05-19 17:52:08.125 10421-10526/? W/Vision: Failed to open download_details.json in com.google.android.gms.vision: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.vision
05-19 17:52:08.126 10421-10526/? I/Vision: Attempting to open download_details.json in com.google.android.gms.policy_ccocr_vision
05-19 17:52:08.127 10421-10526/? W/Vision: Failed to open download_details.json in com.google.android.gms.policy_ccocr_vision: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.policy_ccocr_vision
05-19 17:52:08.127 10421-10526/? W/Vision: Reading download details from hard-coded Java
05-19 17:52:08.443 10421-10526/? E/Vision: Download Failed: Status{statusCode=Download errored: The download was configured incorrectly., resolution=null}
```

Similar questions:

1. [Google Vision barcode library not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32099530/google-vision-barcode-library-not-found)
2. [FaceDetectorHandle﹕ Native face detector not yet available. Reverting to no-op detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062803/facedetectorhandle-native-face-detector-not-yet-available-reverting-to-no-op-d)

Tried the solution with freeing up space, clearing cache, no result.

What can I do next ? Is it possible to manually download the libraries ? Does anyone have a clear indication why is the library not downloading ?

***EDIT***

So it looks like there is an issue with the Mobile Vision api https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/98. Hope the developers come with a solution soon.

***EDIT***

The issue has been resolved by updating the play service library.

Comment: did you add that metadata tag to your manifest?

Comment: Yes. It already comes with <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="face" />.

Comment: Have you check the [Release Notes for May 2016 - v.9.0](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#may_2016_-_v90)? According to the document, "A service required by Mobile Vision is now disabled due to a serious bug in that service. This will prevent users who have not already used face or barcode detection from using those features. We do not recommend adding new Mobile Vision features to your app until this issue is fixed." User FaceDetector.isOperational() to confirm detector readiness before using the face or barcode detector. I hope this helps.

Comment: So what it basically says is that if you have play services v.9.0 is not working. Any news when will they get this fixed ?

Comment: See this GitHub issue here:  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/issues/98

Comment: There was a bug fix in the latest Google Play Services: https://developers.google.com/vision/release-notes#bug_fixes

Answer (score 0):

According to the release notes of Google Play Services v9.0 there was a bug in the service and it was disabled.

In release v9.2 it was enabled again. Check out the release notes:
https://developers.google.com/vision/release-notes#bug_fixes

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with text (TextRecognizer) not face and the problem was storage, I had 300MB free but it needed 10% of my phone according to this link

[When is the intent ACTION_DEVICE_STORAGE_LOW broadcasted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117881/when-is-the-intent-action-device-storage-low-broadcasted)