# Google Play Services Vision check availability

Tags: android, google-play-services

I've tried to use GooglePlayServices Vision package in my app. I've tried in 4 devices and 3 give me that "dependencies are not yet available" on

```
BarcodeDetector barcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(context).build();
if(!barcodeDetector.isOperational()){
//show dependencies are not yet available
}
```

The problem is that even if I close and reopen my app, when I go in the ScanQRCodeActivity i obtain always this error.

So I've seen for the PlayServices availability though

```
GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
if(googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
//show dialog
}
```

but it returns always SUCCESS.

My manifest have meta-data

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="barcode" />
```

And my gradle have the

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
```

Anyway, the only thing that works for me is Clear data of Google Play Services, but people that use my app don't know this.
Have you any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: From this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327891/android-vision-face-detector-dependencies-are-not-yet-available), same problem was encountered. You may pick some important points there. Also when you visit the [Google Play Services 9.2 bug fixes](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/release-notes#google_play_services_92), there are some tips that you can follow to resolve some issues.

Answer (score 0):

From this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327891/android-vision-face-detector-dependencies-are-not-yet-available), same problem was encountered. You may pick some important points there. Also when you visit the [Google Play Services 9.2 bug fixes](https://developers.google.com/vision/android/release-notes#google_play_services_92), there are some tips that you can follow to resolve some issues.

Comment: exactly, but isn't true....I use in my phone version 12.6.85, the last one....but I have always the error above...anyway the only thing that I can detect is that barcodeDetector.isOperational() returns always false, and I have to show alert for user to clear data of Google Play Services app? Google this is unacceptable and ridiculous.